# Change class woocommerce on function.php

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to change the woocommerce password reset button class. Is it possible from the function file of the child theme? How can I do?

Comment: This question should be asked of the WooCommerce support team.[Third party plugin support is off-topic here.](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `woocommerce/` folder in your theme if one doesn't already exist.
Then copy the file from `plugins/woocommerce/template/path/to/file.php` to your theme's `/woocommerce/path/to/file.php` and edit the class to your needs.